# combine those $n$ lists without specifying whole $n$ sets explicitly?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request

Suppose I have $n$ lists, How to combine those $n$ lists without specifying whole $n$ sets?

I mean; For a given lists

> list1={{3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 3}}
> list2={{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}

Using the command Flatten, I can do

```
 Flatten[{lists1,lists2},1]
```

Produces what I want. i.e.,

> {{3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}

For the next cases, I do the similar way. But I want to do this more general. For example given $list[1], \cdots, list[n]$ without specifiying all $n$ elements as

```
  Flatten[{list[1], list[2], .... ,list[n]},1]
```

Is there another way to implement the same operation?

Comment: `list1`, `list2` or `list[1]` , `list[2]` ? Why not `Join` and `Flatten` at level 1?

Comment: Maybe `Flatten[Table[Symbol["list" <> IntegerString[i]], {i, 1, 2}]]` ?

Answer (score 2):

From @user1066, I realize this works fine

```
   Flatten[Table[list[i], {i, 1, n}],1]
```

Comment: In the case you consider ( and I think I misunderstood your question), there is also `Array[lst,10]`

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist[i_] := RandomInteger[i, {3, 3}]
Catenate[mylist /@ Range[5]]
```